# How to prove this equality in proportional fairness analysis?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

How to prove: $$\sum_{s=1}^S\left(\frac{y_s-x_s}{x_s}\right)=\bigtriangledown J_\vec x\cdot(\vec y-\vec x)$$ with:    $$J_\vec x=\sum_s\ln(x_s)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $$ J_x = \sum_s \ln(x_s)$$ 
you have 
\begin{align} \nabla J_x &= (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} (\sum_s \ln(x_s)),\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} (\sum_s \ln(x_s)), ...\frac{\partial}{\partial x_S} (\sum_s \ln(x_s)) \bigr)^T
\\&=( \frac{1}{x_1},\frac{1}{x_2},...,\frac{1}{x_S})^T \end{align}
furthermore
\begin{align}
\vec x-\vec y = (x_1-y_1, x_2-y_2,...,x_S-y_S)^T
\end{align}
If you now take the dot product of the two terms you get
\begin{align}
\nabla J_x \cdot (\vec x-\vec y) & = ( \frac{1}{x_1},\frac{1}{x_2},...,\frac{1}{x_S})^T \cdot (x_1-y_1, x_2-y_2,...,x_S-y_S)^T
\\ & =\frac{x_1-y_1}{x_1} + 
\frac{x_2-y_2}{x_2}+ ... +\frac{x_S-y_S}{x_S}\end{align}
Which is your left hand side.